# Laravel 5.5/Angular JWT logout

Tags: php, angular, laravel, authorization, jwt

I have an issue with logging out using [JWT package](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth). On Angular side I am removing the token from local storage and calling Laravel API:

```
logout(): void {
    this.cacheHandler.clearCache();

    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + 'logout')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            const responseData = response.json();
            return responseData.success;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return error;
        });
}
```

And on Laravel side:

```
public function logout()
{
    try {
        JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Logout successful'], 200);
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Failed to logout, please try again.'], 500);
    }
}
```

API method is protected with JWT auth middleware, so when calling API I am forwarding Authorization Bearer token which was stored in local storage. Method passes, token is valid.

After that it enters the `logout()` method and I am getting the response that logout was successful.

Problem is that I can trigger the same request, with same token, always getting the same message. If it was invalidated, it couldn't trigger the second request because it is behind a middleware.

Also, with the same token, which was supposed to be invalidated, I can call other API methods which require authentication (without the token they don't work)

Answer (score 0):

try using the new JWTGuard and call it like this:

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->guard()->logout(); // pass true to blacklist forever
}
```

That logout functions calls the following code:

```
public function logout($forceForever = false)
{
    $this->requireToken()->invalidate($forceForever);

    $this->user = null;
    $this->jwt->unsetToken();
}
```

Comment: Not working for me...it says: `BadMethodCallException: Method [guard] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController]`